# How to update dependent package version

Tags: angular, karma-runner, tslint, angular10, minimatch

I am working on an Angular 10 project. And as part of the internal audit, I was asked to update the version of `minimatch` to `3.0.5`. I checked my package.json, and I couldn't find the same. But after further research. I found out that, the same package was internally used by many other packages (eg: @angular/cli, karma, tslint etc PFA) I use in my application. All the other packages are using `v3.0.4`.

What can I do about this issue? Any help is appreciated.

[image: Dependencies]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the version 3.0.5 of this specific library in the dependencies of your projects, and it will override it.

Another option is to use this npm if for security vulnerabilities you must update a nested dependency

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions